# Portable Bitfield : Is this Legal

Tags: c++, c++11, bit-fields

I was trying to make a bitfield substitute. The primary motive is to have something that can be easily serialized / deserialized. So I created a bitfield class.

```
template <typename T, size_t ...SIZES>
struct BitField {

   using Type = T;

   template <size_t I>
    void set (T v)
    {
        ...
    }

    template <size_t I>
    T get ()
    {
       ...
    }

    T value_;
};
```

So a bitfiled can be created like below:

```
BitField<uint16_t, 4, 3, 9> field; // creates a 4bit, 3bit and 9bit field in a uint16_t
```

But there is no nice way to set and get the field. With the above interface, we get and set each field by index.

```
field.get<0>()
field.set<0>(10)
```

I wanted to give it a easy syntax, like a variable access and assignment. And I am not clear how I can do it. I created a Field class. The idea is to make a union :

```
struct Mpls {

    using BF = BitField<uint32_t, 20, 3, 1, 8>;

    union  Label {

        BF _bf;

        Field<0, BF> _label; // this will act like a variable
        Field<1, BF> _exp;
        Field<2, BF> _eos;
        Field<3, BF> _ttl;

    } label;
};
```

The Field class is defined as below. But I don't know if this is strictly legal?

```
template <size_t I, typename BF>
struct Field {

    using Type = typename BF::Type;

    void operator = (Type v)
    {
        // typecast 'this' to 'BitField class' and here is where I have doubt if this is okay.
        ((BF *)this)->template set<I>(v);
    }

    operator Type()
    {
        return ((BF *)this)->template get<I>();
    }
};
```

I can set the fields like this.

```
mpls.label._ttl = 0xff;
```

This works. But is it okay to do this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `(BF*)this` exhibits undefined behavior, by trying to access an inactive member of the union.

Comment: Would it be okay, if I construct the BF: `union  Label {
        Label () { new (&_bf) BF(); }
        BF _bf;
        Field<0, BF> _label;
       ....
    } label;
`
Or will it be still UB.

Comment: But then calling `_label.operator=` would be trying to access an inactive member of the union, I think. No matter what you do, you can't pretend that both objects are alive at the same time.

Comment: This seems unnecessary when you could use a `std::bitset<N>`. If you want nice names for specific bits, you can write `std::bitset::reference exp() { return field[0]; } bool exp() const { return field[0]; }` accessors.

Comment: I think bitset only supports single bit fields - On the other hand what I need is bitfields of different sizes. As in the Mpls example - fields are 20bit wide or 3bit wide etc. I can always have accessor functions - but it seems bit tedious to define and use getter and setter for each field.